# SonarQube - Serializable Issue with java.time API

Tags: java, sonarqube

Using `LocalDataTime` and `LocalDate` which are `Serializable` classes in a class which implement the `Serializable` interface. SonarQube is reporting that the code should be updated to "Make "`sampleDateObject`" transient or serializable" though it already implements `Serializable` interface. Any suggestions to fix the issue?

```
public class SampleData implements Serializable {

...
private LocalDateTime sampleDateObject;

public LocalDateTime getSampleDateObject() {
        return sampleDateObject;
    }

    public void setSampleDateObject(LocalDateTime sampleDateObject) {
        this.sampleDateObject= sampleDateObject;
    }
 .....
}
```

Here is the code snippet from Java 1.8 API

```
public final class LocalDateTime
        implements Temporal, TemporalAdjuster, ChronoLocalDateTime<LocalDate>, Serializable {
....
}
```

Below is the description from SonarQube when it fails to identify java element as serializable and error I see is "Make "sampleDateObject" transient or serializable"..

Fields in a `Serializable` class must themselves be either `Serializable` or transient even if the class is never explicitly serialized or deserialized. That's because under load, most J2EE application frameworks flush objects to disk, and an allegedly `Serializable` object with non-transient, non-serializable data members could cause program crashes, and open the door to attackers.

Noncompliant Code Example

```
 public class Address {
      //...
     }

public class Person implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1905122041950251207L;

  private String name;
  private Address address;  // Noncompliant; Address isn't serializable
}
```

Compliant Example

```
public class Address implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2405172041950251807L;
}

public class Person implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1905122041950251207L;

  private String name;
  private Address address;
}
```

Comment: Which versions of the scanner and SonarJava plugin you use?

Comment: Jacoco plugin 0.8.1 version

Comment: I asked you about version of [SonarJava](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/java.html) (installed on SonarQube server) and [Sonar Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN) (used to run analysis) :)

Comment: Sonar Runner 2.4 and Java 1.8.0_60

Comment: `SonarJava` is not JDK, but a plugin installed on SonarQube server (see [Marketplace documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Marketplace)).